# Crash on accessing "sender" of CCMenuItemImage Block

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I'm using the CCMenuItemImage in my code and i want to access the position of the menu item 
when it is clicked but accessing sender variable of block cause the crash.

Following is the code

```
CCMenuItemImage *menuItem = [CCMenuItemImage itemFromNormalSprite:image selectedSprite:selimage block:^(id sender) {
            NSLog(@"Description = %@",[(CCNode*)sender description]);
        }];
```

Images from Debug Window

[image]

[image]

Comment: you can write this to get the same result (not the crashing part): NSLog(@"Description = %@", sender);

Comment: @LearnCocos2D yup thanks, anything about crash??

Comment: not really, looks like sender is corrupt.